# Drawing a continuous, curvy line in OpenGL with arbitrary width

Tags: opengl-es, drawing, width, line, smoothing

I'm looking to draw a continuous and curvy line in OpenGL with an arbitrary width. I am developing for a touch screen and have already achieved the desired effect by drawing lines between the old X & Y coordinates and the new X & Y coordinates. As the user swipes their finger across the screen, this produces a line following their finger. To ensure the line was smooth, I used the following:

```
pGL.glEnable(GL10.GL_LINE_SMOOTH); 
pGL.glHint(GL10.GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
```

However, this essentially means I cannot control the width of the line, as it always defaults to 1. Therefore, I concluded that I'm going to have to come up with some other way to create this effect.

Comment: Are you using OpenGL, or OpenGL ES? Which version? These affect possible solutions a lot.

Comment: The spec says that a specific range of widths is supported when line anti-aliasing is enabled. Are your desired widths outside of that range? Use `glGet` with `GL_ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE` to get the value for your platform.

Comment: I'm using OpenGL ES 1.0 I believe. I haven't run glGet yet but I tried a range of values from 1 to 1000 and according to the guidelines it should round to the nearest supported value but it always remained at 1px.

Comment: On the iPhone, using OpenGL ES 1.0, the line drawing support is limited to 1 pix wide as you already discovered, you must 'triangulate' your lines.

Comment: And of course, anti-aliasing isn't free when doing polys yourself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a line use a quad strip or a triangle strip, centered along the stroke, and with the desired width.

#### EDIT due to comment

Drawing a thick line using quads or triangles is done the following way:

The upper left 3×3 submatrix of the modelview is the rotational part. You want to draw the line with thicknes in screen space, i.e. reverse the local rotation. To do this you need the inverse of the modelview rotation. Rotations are orthogonal transformations, so `inverse(M) = transpose(M)`.

Technically we're interested in only the reverse projected Z axis "Z_local". We can simply take the 3rd row vector of the modelview matrix for this, with the last element "w" being set to zero and the whole vector normalized, i.e.

```
Z_local_i = MV_i,3
```

Next we need the line tangent vector. This is as simple as the direction between the line segments. Or more mathematically, if the line is described by a function C(t), then the tangent is

```
T=∂C(t)/∂t
```

We can now take the cross product between tangent and Z_local, giving us a normal

```
N(t) = Z_local × T(t)
```

Adding the normal N(t) to C(t) gives us a equidistant curve parallel to C. This allows us to draw quads:

```
for t in range(0, T):
    T = deriv(C(t), t)
    N = cross(Z_local, T)
    emit_vertex(C(t) + width*N)
    emit_vertex(C(t) - width*N)
```

Comment: One thing, will I still be able to achieve a smooth effect by using quad/triangle strips?

Comment: @user908041: Yes, either use Full Screen Anti Aliasing (FSAA, Multisample Buffers). Or you can just use a 1D texture with some falloff toward the borders.

Comment: Hi again, thanks for your help earlier, but I haven't quite been able to figure out how I should go about drawing a triangle strip along the stroke as you suggested earlier. How would you suggest I go about doing this given the starting X&Y coordinates and the ending coordinates of the stroke? Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks so much for such a detailed response, although the quad/triangle strip I'm trying to create only uses x&y, not Z

Comment: I'm just afraid of tight curves, where the triangle strip might intersect itself. Does this have any visual implications?